# Flyway 3.0 Migration Checksum mismatch

Tags: maven, flyway

after upgrading Flyway Maven plugin from 2.3 to 3.0 I get:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:3.0:migrate (default-cli) on project
>   xxx: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed. Found
>   differences between applied migrations and available migrations:
>   Migration Checksum mismatch for migration
>   V003__data_feed_sources_locations.sql: DB=942424992,
>   Classpath=1117634405 -> [Help 1]

Got a similar error on some other project.

If I downgrade back to 2.3 the migration runs ok. Does this has something to do with different platform encoding for calculating checksums?

Any workaround, or better yet, proper solution?

Comment: if anyone on spring boot app, then please add in app.yml this line else it won't work `spring.flyway.validateOnMigrate: false` and you can still use latest flyway version no repairing nothing needed.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Flyway 3.0 changed the default of validateOnMigrate to true.

This is however a good thing, as in the spirit of fail fast, errors are discovered sooner.

In your case some scripts did change since they were applied, which is what Flyway is reporting.

You have two options:

- suppress the error by setting validateOnMigrate to false (2.3 default behavior)
- invoke `Flyway.repair()` to reallign the checksums

*Reference*
[Flyway Repair](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/repair)

Comment: Hi, I am reading http://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/repair.html and there is indeed a line saying "Correct wrong checksums", but when I run the "mvn flyway:repair" on 2.3 or 3.0 version of the plugin I get: "Repair of metadata table `xyz`.`schema_version` not necessary. No failed migration detected.". Is there a hidden option or command line switch to recalculate hashes?

Comment: It should have repaired the checksums anyway. Flyway 3.0 is missing a message to tell you so. The message will be included in 3.1.

Comment: Before running the repair goal I checked and saved the checksum value from the schema_version flyway db table to verify the checksum will be modified, but it was not.

Comment: OK. Please file an issue with the exact steps to reproduce and we'll get it fixed for 3.1.

Comment: I tried repair option but it did not worked for me, I too got "Repair of metadata table xyz.schema_version not necessary. No failed migration detected." So I set validateOnMigrate to false and it worked.

Comment: If you are starting the application from the command line, use the flag `--flyway.validate-on-migrate=false`

Comment: @PedroMadrid That's a Spring Boot flag, not a Flyway flag. Don't confuse them!

Comment: if anyone on spring boot app, then please add in app.yml this line else it won't work `spring.flyway.validateOnMigrate: false` and you can still use latest flyway version no repairing nothing needed.

Answer (score 24):

To add to Axel Fontaine's answer:

I was able to use mvn flyway:repair but I had to point the `flyway.locations` config property at the folder that contains my db migration scripts. Otherwise I would get the message "Repair of metadata table xyz.schema_version not necessary. No failed migration detected." like other folks mentioned.

I used `mvn -Dflyway.locations=filesystem:<project dir>/src/main/resources/db/migrations flyway:repair` and I saw the checksum updated in the metadata table, fixing my problem.

Comment: With a bare flyway run use something similar to this: FLYWAY_LOCATIONS="filesystem:/path/to/migrations/sql" /usr/local/bin/flyway migrate

Answer (score 10):

First, it looks for checksum changes. These changes occur if we update migration files which are already applied to a db instance.

**FlywayException**: Validate failed: Migration checksum mismatch for migration version 18.2.6

-> Applied to database : 90181454

-> Resolved locally    : 717386176

**repair()** method would fix up checksum issue by updating the **flyway_schema_history** table with local checksum value.

However, it would neglect updated statements in same migration file. So, new changes in same file would be neglected as there is already an entry for version in **flyway_schema_history** table. setValidateOnMigrate() method has no effect in this scenario. We should follow incremental approach, schema changes should be supplied through new files.

Answer (score 9):

I found the easiest way to resolve this issue was to literally update the checksum in the schema table to the value flyway expected.  I knew for a fact that my migration files had not changed and that the current state of the database was what it needed to be.  I also did not want to spend time reading documentation and messing around with `Flyway.repair()` or other methods that could *potentially* mess things up even more.  A simple sql update resolved it right away

Comment: We do something similar for our deploys. There is a bit of code in startup that checks to see if certain checksums for specific version migration files are not what we want and repairs them on the fly before startup. We've had to do this in the past when we discovered a bug in an older migration script that only hits edge cases. We update the script, add this little bit of code to fix the checksum for existing systems so that future migrations don't have issues. Probably not the best way but it works for us.

Answer (score 2):

The issue happen right after I changed the V1_2__books.sql ddl file, There should be a better way to force flyway to recognize the new changes!!!

I tried to run mvn flyway:repair but it did not work, I ended up changing the schema url in the application.properties file [datasource.flyway.url] to books2

I removed the below files as well (books is my old schema name )

```
~ @~:rm books.mv.db 
~ @~:rm -r books.trace.db
```

```js
datasource.flyway.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/books2
datasource.flyway.username=sa
datasource.flyway.password=
datasource.flyway.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

I ran the application and BINGO :)

Answer (score 2):

Invoke `Flyway.repair()` directly from configurations.

Add below bean to your configuration class or create a new class with `@Congiguration` annotation and add the below code.

```
    @Bean
    public FlywayMigrationStrategy repairFlyway() {
        return flyway -> {
            // repair each script's checksum
            flyway.repair();
            // before new migrations are executed
            flyway.migrate();
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add, that in order for the checksum to be updated by repair. Flyway has to have access to the directory where all the migrations are. Otherwise flyway just goes about it's business and outputs

> "Repair of failed migration in metadata table `xyz`.`schema_version` not necessary. No failed migration detected."

Answer (score 1):

The checksum needs to be updated using the flyway repair command (run the Flyway command as stated in “Upgrade procedure” but replace “migrate” with “repair”).

I recommend you do not intrude directly to database, sql scripts, etc. It can be dangerous

Example:
./flyway **repare** -user=root -password=changeme -url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mypath -table=my_flyway_schema_version_table -locations=filesystem:/mypath_sql_scripts

Answer (score 1):

if you are running on local db u can delete the flyway_schema_history  table

Comment: how do you delete it? where is it located exactly?

Comment: mostly in you db public schema .There will be a flyway table named 'schema_version_*'

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a local database and you encounter a checksum mismatch error, you can delete the rows from the Flyway schema history table starting from the version that is causing the mismatch. After that, you can rerun the migrations and Flyway will apply the migrations again and generate new checksums.

Comment: Won't re-running migrations on top of a database where the changes are already applied possibly cause errors?

Answer (score -4):

There is yet another solution. You can drop your migration from **schema_version** table.

Comment: Double operation will happen incase of insert, update or delete query